# Ruby Mine complains that "Cannot switch SDK." even if the SDK is there and available

Tags: ruby, rvm, rubymine

My Ruby Mine 6.0.3 gives the message:

```
Project .ruby-version Settings: Cannot switch SDK. RVM SDK '2.1.1@rails3' wasn't found.
```

I manage ruby environments with rvm. 
The wanted environment seems to be ok:

```
rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-2.1.1 (found in /home/agostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1)
    (default)
    global
    rails3 
=>  testproject
```

Not only this, but also Mine seems to access the rvm environments quite well since opening File, Settings i can see:

[image: Ruby Mine 6.03, File, Settings, Ruby SDK and Gems]

So why can't it switch to the correct environment?

If, in the form above, I select it manually, it seems to work fine. But the "cannot switch..." message still appears each time I open the project.

Comment: I've got those errors with `6.0.3` too, I'm adding now `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset`(I'm using RVM) to every project and it doesn't complain now.

Comment: I have such files in their place. The files themselves are the place where Ruby Mine sees that i would use the gemset: 2.1.1@rails3. So it knows well of their presence. But the same, it doesn't "switch".

Comment: Maybe try removing `.idea`? I 'fixed' a lot of RM 6.x errors with that, 5.x versions were much better, at least when related to strange errors like that.

Comment: BTW still the same situation in Rubymine 7.0.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found for a similar problem (Rubymine 6.3.1 and Ruby 2.1.1) that I had to format .ruby-version in the following way:

```
ruby-2.1.1
```

Note the prefix 'ruby-" to the version number.  I'm not sure whether this is an RVM, Ruby, Rubymine, or some other issue that caused this problem, but the fix I mentioned worked on my Mac.

Comment: Now it gives a nice message: Project .ruby-version Settings
           According to mytest project .ruby-version file Ruby SDK was changed
           to RVM: ruby-2.1.1 [rails3.2.17]"

Comment: @AgostinoX make sure you also have the gemset created (if your project has one set), I had also this problem, got fixed by just creating the gemset

Comment: Using RM 6.3.3. `.ruby-version` has `ruby-2.1.2` as the contents. Still getting the error. Not sure what to do. I chose to follow the steps mentioned below, by [AbuShady](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23282231/174936).

Comment: This appears to have been addressed and should hopefully be resolved in Satsuki: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15058

Comment: My  .ruby-version file is correctly formatted as `ruby-2.2.0`, but I still see the same error everytime.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is the case, but you might be telling rubymine to use a different ruby version, and it uses that version on all the commands, that's why it shows the errors on each interaction with ruby.

You need to change the running configuration, from the menu choose: <kbd>Run</kbd> > <kbd>Edit configuration</kbd>

Then you'll find few settings on the left, choose the one that you use to run your project, and on the right check for `Ruby SDK`, choose the correct ruby version from the list, and click ok. Every thing should be fine, you might need to bundle because gems aren't shared between different ruby versions.

Comment: For some reason, I'd tried this before and had no success, but it magically worked this time. I think this is the correct answer regardless, because RubyMine should cater to the version of ruby my team is using especially thanks to rvm.

Answer (score 2):

FYI this issue has been already reported to JetBrains [RUBY-15058](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15058) and it seems they will work on adding "ruby-" prefix if missing.